# Set SQL query through PHP variable that changes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $var _table";
```

I have two tables called:

1. cool_table
2. uncool_table

The solution I want is to be able to create a SQL query that is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $var_table";
```

Where `$var` changes, but not `_table`.

I have passed the variable through, so no worries there. My question is can I change $var to the appropriate table name? I can't connect the two because it goes $var_table and becomes a new variable (which doesn't exist).

Apologies if this is a repeat, but I don't know how else to phrase the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$var."_table";
```

Comment: I did this! I used `.` and `+` and who knows what else and it didn't work! I feel like such a maroon. Thanks.